# How does java.io.InputStream.read() work?

Tags: java, syntax, io

Why does this :

```
import java.io.*;

class ioTest2 {
  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
      int b;
      while( (b = System.in.read() ) != -1)
          System.out.print((char)b);
  }
}
```

work as expected,i.e print exactly what you type, and this:

```
import java.io.*;

class ioTest2 {
  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
    int b;
    while( (b = System.in.read() ) != -1)
        System.out.print(b);
  }
}
```

does not? Why do I have cast `b` to a character to make the code correct?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? `PrintStream#print(int)` exists and should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`read()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) returns an `int` that stores the next byte that is read from the stream.  You need to cast it to a `char`, or otherwise the `int` value will be printed.

If you type "ABCD", then without casting, then the [`println(int)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-int-) is called (`System.out` is a `PrintStream`), and the values of the bytes are printed.

```
  B   D
  vv  vv
65666768
^^  ^^
A   C
```

If you cast it to a `char`, then a different overloaded method, [`println(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-char-) is called, which knows to print the character specified, so it "works" (echoes to you the characters you typed).

Answer (score 0):

The `read()` method [returns an integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()), or -1 if the end of stream has been reached.

A `char`, or character, is a [primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), and can be represented as a number. Since you cast the integer to a character, it's represented on screen.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print((char)b)` calls a *different method* from `System.out.print(b)`.  They do different things.

Which method to call is not just determined by the name, but by the name and the *type signature* (i.e., by the types of the arguments).  Different methods can have the same name, so long as they have different argument lists.

Read the JavaDoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28int%29

Versus

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28char%29